# Tem como auto incrementar o id no mongo?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, mongodb

Tem como fazer isto, toda a vez que eu criar um novo usuário por exemplo ele fazer o auto incremento do _id. Começando de 1 e indo até o numero de usuários

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, seguindo o exemplo da documentação([create-an-auto-incrementing-field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)), seria algo assim:

1 - Insira na coleção de contadores, o valor inicial para o campo:

```
db.counters.insert(
   {
      _id: "userid",
      seq: 0
   }
)
```

2 - Crie uma função `getNextSequence` que aceite um nome da seqüência. A função usa o método `findAndModify()` para atomicamente incrementar o valor `seq` e retornar esse novo valor:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );
return ret.seq;
}
```

3 - Use esta função `getNextSequence()` durante a inserção.

```
db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Sarah C."
   }
)

db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Bob D."
   }
)
```

Maiores informações vide a documentação.

Answer (score 1):

Na própria documentação do MongoDB tem um exemplo e te mostra como fazer. Inclusive eles dizem que o método utilizado é mais recomentado para o _id, justamente o que você precisa. Da uma olhada [AQUI](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).